How to only get a value from a table?
I want to extract a specific value from a table and do some calculations with it and insert the solution into an other table. The calculation includes an user input.
I get a runtime error: unsopported value[{"b" : A}].
I suppoes that I get a key value pair from the sql statement. BUt I want only to get the value.
How do I get only a value from a table or how do I seperate the key and the value?
d = int(request.form.get("e")
a = db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT b FROM c WHERE column= :column_name", column_name=data)
a = a*d 
db.execute("INSERT INTO f(g) VALUE (?)", a)

I tried to change the type of the database, but it didn't work.
I searched for other SELECT statements to only get the value, but I didn't found a pleasing one.
I tried let value = array.from(a.value).
Now I am frustrated. If you have an idea, please let me know.

db.execute() returns a list of all the result rows, and each of these is a dictionary where the column names are keys and column values are the values.
So you have to index a to get the value you want:
b = a[0]['b']
g = b * d
db.execute("INSERT INTO f(g) VALUE (?)", g)

But there's no need to do this with two queries, you can do it one:
db.execute('''
    INSERT INTO f (g)
    SELECT DISTINCT b * :multiplier
    FROM c
    WHERE column= :column_name
''', column_name = data, multiplier = d)


Thanks, is there a way I can do addition with all inserted values?

I don't understand what you mean by that. Add them where?

I want to do addition with some values in the table and add them in an other column in the table.

Like SELECT DISTINCT column1 * :multiplier + column2 ...?
